# Single command to display logs from running kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Want to have a single command to have continue streaming of logs from particular pod. Currently I have to do

- `kubectl get pods` (lists all the running pods)
- check for the running pod from the list and copy the pod name
- `kubectl logs <pod name> -f` (continuous streaming of logs from pod)

Bonus points: list pods starting with certain word like, `kubectl get pods asset*`. Which would just display pods with names starting with asset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally was able to figure out the solution. This would be somewhat hacky, but I would basically use `--field-selector=status.phase=Running` and just get the name with `-o=name` flag.
My final command would be something like

```
kubectl logs -f $(kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running -o=name | awk '/asset/ {print $1;exit}')
```

Links: [Field Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to achieve this. You can use:

```
kubectl logs -n <namespace> $(kubectl get pod -n <namespace> |  awk '/<pattern>/{print $1}') -f
```

Here, you can specify regex in `<pattern>` field. `print $1` prints only first column of matched object. In our case, it is pod name.

For example:

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get pod -n kube-system |  awk '/kube-proxy*/{print $1}') -f
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all result by `kubectl get pods` and `grep` can do the rest of things.

```
[root@k8s-m1 ~]# kubectl get pods | grep httpd*-app
httpd-app-66cb7d499b-4nfl4   1/1     Running   0          6m39s
httpd-app-66cb7d499b-c2blq   1/1     Running   0          6m39s
httpd-app-66cb7d499b-dt4tr   1/1     Running   0          6m39s
```

Comment: This particular command would not differentiate between pods with different status. I just want pods with Running status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some bash tricks to get that :

Example:

Get the logs for pod starting with name pattern **core** in kube-system namespace.

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | grep core)
```

or even simple:

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods -o=name --all-namespaces | grep core)
```

but in production you should use fluentbit to stream the logs to ELK and then use filters in kibana UI to get the logs for each pod/deployment/namespace etc.

https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging

Answer (score 0):

Just run below one liner for " Single command to display logs from running kubernetes pod "

```
kubectl get pods -n default|grep Running|awk '{print $1}'|while read pods;do echo "Pod name is $pods" ;kubectl logs $pods;echo;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a kubectl plugin with the name "kubectl-tail"

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && { echo "Try kubectl tail RESOURCE_NAME"; exit 1; }

# this wil find only one pod in my case
# you can modify it if you have more than one with the same name 
pod=$(kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running -o=name|awk -v res="$1" '$1 ~ res && !/debug$/')
     
[ -z "$pod" ] && { echo "No pod found!"; exit 0; }

kubectl logs -f "$pod"
```

Put the script in your PATH and make ist executable

Check it

```
$ kubectl plugin list
The following compatible plugins are available:
/home/ufopilot/bin/kubectl-tail
```

Now you can use it

```
kubectl tail asset
```